# use a gradient for a d3 diagonal based on node values

Tags: tree, d3.js, gradient, diagonal

i am trying to understand how to use gradients based on values of the nodes.  i have figured out how to do gradients based on arbitrary colors, like "pink" -> "yellow", but i am trying to figure out how to have the diagonal gradient go from a value based on the source and target nodes. my project is based on mike bostock's "Collapsible Tree":  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

here is the relevant code. i've looked high and low trying to figure out how to do this.

my nodes have a value ".epoch" which is between min_epoch and max_epoch and are colored based on this code:

```
function epochColor(d) {
  var blueRed = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([min_epoch, max_epoch])
    .range(["blue", "red"]);
  return blueRed(d);
}

function myEpochColor(d) {
  return (epochColor(d.epoch));
}
```

i've tried any number of variations to get a the gradient to go from the value of the target to source but with no luck. i think the problem is that when the gradient code is evaluated it knows nothing about the nodes. i tried putting in a .call(function)...  with no love.

```
.link {
  fill:         none;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  opacity:      1.00;
  stroke:       url(#myEpochGradient);
}
```

...

```
var gradient = svg.append("svg:defs")
    .append("svg:linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "myEpochGradient")
      .attr("gradientUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
      .attr("x1",   "0%").attr("y1", "0%")
      .attr("x2", "100%").attr("y2", "0%");
    gradient.append("svg:stop")
      .attr("offset", "0%")
      .attr("stop-opacity", 1)
      .attr("stop-color", function(d) {return myEpochColor(d.source)});
    gradient.append("svg:stop")
      .attr("offset",   "100%")
      .attr("stop-opacity", 1)
      .attr("stop-color", function(d) {return myEpochColor(d.target)});
```

any help in figuring this out would be hugely appreciated.

tia - keith

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some confusion here about how gradient defs work in SVG. Even if the code above worked, you wouldnt be able to get it to work for all your nodes, because every time you changed the stops you'd change them for everything that references the gradient. You're going to need at least one gradient definition for *every* color-color transition you need.

Most likely the easiest way to do this (though I can't speak to its rendering performance) is to add a new gradient to each `g` element for each link, then set its stops based on the source and target nodes of the link. Give it a unique id and then reference it in the diagonal element. The code you have above for the gradient should mostly work, IFF instead of appending to the SVG you append to the `g` element *with the link data bound to it* - the main problem with your code as it stands is that you don't bind any data anywhere, so the gradient element has nothing to reference in the `stop-color` function.

Comment: You are right - I am confused. I thought I could define a gradient just like a color. I'll try adding the gradient to each `g` element and see how it goes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just try converting my c# code into which language you want. it will give you a gradient by the color values and the number you send as parameter

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using SDColor = System.Drawing.Color;

    //Developed by امین امیری دربان
    namespace APREndUser.CodeAssist
    {
        public static class ColorHelper
        {
            public static SWMColor ToSWMColor(SDColor color) => SWMColor.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
            public static SDColor ToSDColor(SWMColor color) => SDColor.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
            public static SWMBrush ToSWMBrush(SDColor color) => (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(ToHexColor(color)));
            public static string ToHexColor(SDColor c) => "#" + c.R.ToString("X2") + c.G.ToString("X2") + c.B.ToString("X2");
            public static string ToRGBColor(SDColor c) => "RGB(" + c.R.ToString() + "," + c.G.ToString() + "," + c.B.ToString() + ")";
            public static Tuple<SDColor, SDColor> GetColorFromRYGGradient(double percentage)
            {
                var red = (percentage > 50 ? 1 - 2 * (percentage - 50) / 100.0 : 1.0) * 255;
                var green = (percentage > 50 ? 1.0 : 2 * percentage / 100.0) * 255;
                var blue = 0.0;
                SDColor result1 = SDColor.FromArgb((int)red, (int)green, (int)blue);
                SDColor result2 = SDColor.FromArgb((int)green, (int)red, (int)blue);
                return new Tuple<SDColor, SDColor>(result1, result2);
            }
        }

    }
```